# Не могу найти ошибку

Tags: php

```
echo "<font color=green>$dati[2].$dati[1].$dati[0]</font>
      <a href=\"news.php?cont=long&id=$idnum&year=$dati[0]&today=$dati[2]&month=$dati[1]\">
      <b>$title</b></a>";
```

пишет синтаксическая ошибка

Answer (score 1):

```
echo("<font color=green>".$dati[2].$dati[1].$dati[0]."</font><a href='news.php?cont=long&id=".$idnum."&year=".$dati[0]."&today=".$dati[2]."&month=".$dati[1]."'><b>".$title."</b></a>";
```

Вроде ничего не пропустил

UPD: поправил

Comment: спасибо, вышло!

Comment: только теперь новая вылезла)
$monthlong = date("F",mktime(1,1,1,$month,$today,$year));

Comment: Вот тут ещё ошибка: `$idnum.&year.`

Comment: Pink Tux, с чего вдруг там ошибка?

Comment: @AlinaOvchinnikova подробнее, какая ошибка?

Comment: опять синтаксическая

Comment: "с чего вдруг там ошибка" - должно быть: `$idnum."&year="`

Comment: @PinkTux действительно, я проморгал, подумал что знак & это $, сейчас обновлю пост, спасибо

Comment: послностью можете написать? а то я в этом новичок)))

Comment: @AlinaOvchinnikova обновил пост

Comment: да, спасибо) но здесь всё равно выдаёт ошибку

Comment: $monthlong = date("F",mktime(1,1,1,$month,$today,$year));

Comment: @AlinaOvchinnikova полностью ошибку скопируйте и напишите сюда

Comment: то что исправили, сайт вообще перестал грузиться)))

Comment: могу полность файл скинуть

Comment: @AlinaOvchinnikova сбрасывайте

Comment: @EatMyDust а можно почту или куда сбросить, потому что сюда как то не получается(

Comment: Если код небольшой обновите ваш вопрос и добавьте его через bbcode, если большой залейте на файлообменник и пришлите ссылку